# Edit Collection on Opensea

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, opensea

My collection lives on a deployed contract on Rinkeby right now. If I go to Opensea and click on `Create Collection` (from the profile menu), I can edit all the elements of the page, but there doesn't seem to be a way to relate that to the deployed contract. On the other hand, if I click on `Import an existing smart contract', I get the a page but there doesn't seem to be any way to edit it, even though I'm logged in with the same address I used to deploy the Contract. Am I supposed to be passing the metadata directly from the contract or.. what am I missing here please?

Comment: Do you have a working snippet code to add all of those attrs while we're uploading to the collection with ERC1155? My issue is my collectionX is not listed under my collections and, when I add `/edit` to the collection URL, it says you are not authorized to edit. I'm using a simple contract extended from ERC1155 and calling `_mint` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensea is a front end for the blockchain, and doesn't actually (currently) offer "no-code" ways to change what is on-chain.

When you change your elements and create collections through the UI on Opensea, you're just changing that information in the Opensea database, not on-chain.

If you want to update the on-chain contract, you'll have to actually code that piece in.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for your answer. I was actually asking how to edit the attributes of the collection in Opensea. Turns out you have to do it through a contract function called contractURI which returns a json similar to how each token has its toeknURI. Still not sure how to set the banner image and the logo tho...  https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata

Comment: To edit the attributes, yes, you'll have to have a tokenURI that has those attributes. The banner at the top should be editable by whomever minted the contract.

Answer (score 0):

When you "Import an existing smart contract", you can edit the metadata on OS as long as:

1. You've added [`contractURI`](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata) to your contract
2. Your contract is [`Ownable`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control) as mentioned [in the Help Centre](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/4403934341907-How-do-I-import-my-contract-automatically-)
3. You're logged in OS with the contract `owner` account

Note: It just takes a few hours for the option to edit the collection to show up.